# How to use a numpy boolean array to modify another numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a boolean array that looks like this:

```
arr_a = np.array(
[[False, False, False],
[True, True, True],
[True, True, True],
[False, False, False]]
)
```

and another array that looks like this:

```
arr_b = np.array(
[[100, 100, 100],
[200, 200, 200]]
)
```

I am looking for a function that I can call like this: `np.boolean_combine(arr_a, arr_b)`, to return an array that will replace the 1's in arr_a with the values from arr_b, for an end result that looks like this:

```
np.array(
[[0, 0, 0]
[100, 100, 100],
[200, 200, 200],
[0, 0, 0]]
)
```

Is there such a function?

Comment: Will the shapes always be a match?  So will `arra_b.size` always equal the number of `True` in `arr_a`?

Comment: Yes, the shapes will always be a match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new array of the same `dtype` as `arra_b`, take a slice view using `arr_a` an assign the values from `arra_b`:

```
out = arr_a.astype(arra_b.dtype)
out[arr_a] = arra_b.ravel()

array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [100, 100, 100],
       [200, 200, 200],
       [  0,   0,   0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your arr_a is made of 1's and 0's:

```
import numpy as np 
arr_a = np.array(
[[0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0]])
arra_b = np.array(

[[100, 100, 100],

[200, 200, 200]])


arr_a[np.where(arr_a)]  = arra_b.reshape(arr_a[np.where(arr_a)].shape)
```

This works, assuming that the shapes are a match

Comment: Here is what this returned:

>>> arr_a = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
>>> arra_b = np.array([[100, 100, 100],[200, 200, 200]])
>>> arr_a[np.where(arr_a)]  = arra_b.reshape(arr_a[np.where(arr_a)].shape)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6 into shape (3,)

Comment: I just ran it again and it works without an error. Check the edit to my answer to see if my arrays a and b are equal to yours

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()`. Supposing that arr_a and arr_b are (obviously, from your problem) of the same dimension:

```py
def boolean_combine(arr_a, arr_b) -> np.array:
  combined = []
  for row_a, row_b in zip(arr_a, arr_b):
    row_combined = []
    for a, b in zip(row_a, row_b):
      if a == 'True':
        row_combined.append(b)
      else:
        row_combined.append(a)
    combined.append(np.asarray(row_combined))
  return np.asarray(combined)
```

Then, you can call this function in your main just by typing `combined = boolean_combine(arr_a, arr_b)`